# How to create a class that one of its object is in the type of another class in VB?

Tags: vb.net, class

Following is my code

```
Class LIVandOSA
    Public LIV_ As String
    Public OSA_ As String
End Class

Class TestUnitID
    Public SMPSdata As LIVandOSA
    Public SMdata As LIVandOSA
    Public COATEDBARdata As LIVandOSA
    Public CLCLdata As LIVandOSA

    Public Sub New(ByVal s As String)
        SMPSdata.LIV_ = s
    End Sub
End Class
```

In the main program, I wrote the following code to create a list of `TestUnitID` and add some element into it.

```
    Dim a As New List(Of TestUnitID)
    a.Add(New TestUnitID("a1.csv"))
    a.Add(New TestUnitID("a2.csv"))
    TextBox1.Text = a(0).SMPSdata.LIV_
```

But when I try to compile it, it gives me the following error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

And the error cursor was pointing to the line `SMPSdata.LIV_(s)`

How should I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory, you haven't initialized that object.

Since you are in the constructor it is a good place to initialize fields and properties:

```
Class TestUnitID
    Public SMPSdata As LIVandOSA
    Public SMdata As LIVandOSA
    Public COATEDBARdata As LIVandOSA
    Public CLCLdata As LIVandOSA

    Public Sub New(ByVal s As String)
        Me.SMPSdata = New LIVandOSA()
        Me.SMdata = New LIVandOSA()
        Me.COATEDBARdata = New LIVandOSA()
        Me.CLCLdata = New LIVandOSA()

        SMPSdata.LIV_(s)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have initiate it before using the object, therefor you can use

```
Me.SMPSdata = New LIVandOSA()
...
```

to create a new object